# Trying to inject $element into ng-view results in Unknown Provider error

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I wonder if that's a bug or documented somewhere. Seems like injecting $element into controller attached by ng-view directive fails. Here's an example:

script.js:

```
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$element',
    function($route, $routeParams, $location, $element) {
      // Works here
      console.log('MainCtrl', $element);
      this.$route = $route;
      this.$location = $location;
      this.$routeParams = $routeParams;
  }])
  .controller('BookCtrl', ['$routeParams', '$element', function($routeParams, $element) {
    // Broken here
    console.log('BookCtrl', $element);
    this.name = "BookCtrl";
    this.params = $routeParams;
  }])
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/S7ziY6i3eMGn4RtetG0l?p=preview

Comment: `MainCtrl` was injected by `$compile` which provides `$element` as a **local**. `BookCtrl` was injected by `ngRoute` which doesn't provide `$element` as a local. For more information on `$compile` injected **locals**, see [AngularJS $compile -- controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-).

Comment: is there something specific you want to do with the `$element` in these controllers. Maybe there is another way to approach the problem.

Comment: @georgeawg you should post it as answer. seems correct

Comment: @Jaanus After more research I added my answer,

Comment: @Rhumborl, I'm using jQuery plugin that requires an element selector. Solved my problem by rewriting that bit as a directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MainCtrl` was injected by the `$compile` service which provides `$element` as a local. `BookCtrl` was injected by `ngRoute` which doesn't provide `$element` as a local. For more information on `$compile` injected locals, see [AngularJS $compile API Reference -- controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-controller-).

The **locals** that `ngRoute` injects are `$scope`, `$template`, and the other properties of the `$resolve` map.

---

### From the `ngRoute` Docs:

> ### `locals`
>
> A map of locals which is used by [$controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service for
>          controller instantiation. The `locals` contain
>          the resolved values of the `resolve` map. Additionally the `locals` also contain:
>
> - `$scope` - The current route scope.
> - `$template` - The current route template HTML.
>
> The `locals` will be assigned to the route scope's `$resolve` property. You can override
>           the property name, using `resolveAs` in the route definition. See
>           [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for more info.

-- [AngularJS ngRoute $route API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#current)

---

### From the `$compile` Docs:

> ### controller
>
> Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and can be accessed by other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior. The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the **following locals**:
>
> - `$scope` - Current scope associated with the element
> - `$element` - Current element
> - `$attrs` - Current attributes object for the element
> - `$transclude` - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope:

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After a bit of digging around also found this closed issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6988 Basically their reasoning is: it's a route controller, not an element controller, hence it shouldn't require an $element.

Comment: @EugeneKulabuhov It works well with ui-router `0.2.15` where as with `0.2.11` version it didn't work for me :)